# NPE when calling removeRule in Drools

Tags: drools

When I use the API `KnowledgeBaseImpl.removeRule()` in Drools 7.56.0.Final, NPE was thrown.
We use template to create rule, the content is like:

```
package drools.template;\nimport java.text.SimpleDateFormat;\nimport java.util.Date;\n\nrule "651657095963213824-651657096034516992"\n    when\n        $p: com.seewo.ucp.hub.domain.strategy.aggregation.StrategyRule((deviceDto.lamp == com.seewo.ucp.hub.domain.device.enums.DeviceEventTypeEnum.ONLINE) && (date ==1628645220445))\n    then\n        $p.setResult(Boolean.TRUE);\nend\n\n\n
```

The add rule code:

```
    KnowledgeBuilder knowledgeBuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
    knowledgeBuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newByteArrayResource(drlContent.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)), ResourceType.DRL);
    if (knowledgeBuilder.hasErrors()) {
        return;
    }
    ((KnowledgeBaseImpl) kieBase).addPackages(knowledgeBuilder.getKnowledgePackages());
```

The remove rule code:

```
if (isRuleExist(ruleName)) {                   
    kieBase.removeRule(packageName, ruleName);
}
```

Here, `isRuleExist()` is a function to check if the rule exists or not: `kieBase.getRule(packageName, ruleName) != null`.

When I removed the rule, NPE thrown:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.drools.core.phreak.AddRemoveRule.iterateLeftTuple(AddRemoveRule.java:1081) ~[drools-core-7.56.0.Final.jar:7.56.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.phreak.AddRemoveRule.visitChild(AddRemoveRule.java:996) ~[drools-core-7.56.0.Final.jar:7.56.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.phreak.AddRemoveRule.lambda$processLeftTuplesOnLian$1(AddRemoveRule.java:954) ~[drools-core-7.56.0.Final.jar:7.56.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.common.DefaultFactHandle$SingleLinkedTuples.forEachLeftTuple(DefaultFactHandle.java:739) ~[drools-core-7.56.0.Final.jar:7.56.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.common.DefaultFactHandle.forEachLeftTuple(DefaultFactHandle.java:935) ~[drools-core-7.56.0.Final.jar:7.56.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.phreak.AddRemoveRule.processLeftTuplesOnLian(AddRemoveRule.java:949) ~[drools-core-7.56.0.Final.jar:7.56.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.phreak.AddRemoveRule.processLeftTuples(AddRemoveRule.java:870) ~[drools-core-7.56.0.Final.jar:7.56.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.phreak.AddRemoveRule.removeRule(AddRemoveRule.java:179) ~[drools-core-7.56.0.Final.jar:7.56.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.reteoo.ReteooBuilder.removeTerminalNode(ReteooBuilder.java:191) ~[drools-core-7.56.0.Final.jar:7.56.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.reteoo.ReteooBuilder.removeRules(ReteooBuilder.java:177) ~[drools-core-7.56.0.Final.jar:7.56.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.impl.KnowledgeBaseImpl.lambda$removeRule$6(KnowledgeBaseImpl.java:1559) ~[drools-core-7.56.0.Final.jar:7.56.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.impl.KnowledgeBaseImpl.enqueueModification(KnowledgeBaseImpl.java:748) ~[drools-core-7.56.0.Final.jar:7.56.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.impl.KnowledgeBaseImpl.removeRule(KnowledgeBaseImpl.java:1543) ~[drools-core-7.56.0.Final.jar:7.56.0.Final]
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: Please include the code where you remove the rule. (Also when you say that you use a template to create a rule, I really hope you mean a rule template because otherwise you're reinventing the wheel probably less efficiently than the built-in capabilities of drools.)

Comment: The code is:  
`if (isRuleExist(ruleName)) {  
                kieBase.removeRule(packageName, ruleName);   
 }`

isRuleExist() is a function to check the rule exists or not:  
`kieBase.getRule(packageName, ruleName) != null`   

And I use org.drools.template to create a rule.

Comment: I've edited your question to put the code in your comment into the question itself. In the future, please use the 'Edit' link under your question to add missing information instead of doing so in the comments.

Comment: I'm still a little unclear about how those rule templates are working, since when done properly you shouldn't be needing to manually add or remove anything -- see the examples in the docs [here](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latestFinal/drools-docs/html_single/#_rule_templates). It's probably not terribly important in relation to this question, though.